# How to filter a polars dataframe by date?

Tags: python, python-polars

```
df.filter(pl.col("MyDate") >= "2020-01-01")
```

does not work like it does in pandas.

I found a workaround

```
df.filter(pl.col("MyDate") >= pl.datetime(2020,1,1))
```

but this does not solve a problem if I need to use string variables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `pl.lit(my_date_str).str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt=my_date_fmt))`

Building on the example above:

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df=pl.DataFrame({
    "dates": [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 3)],
    "vals": range(3)
})

my_date_str="2021-01-02"
my_date_fmt="%F"
df.filter(pl.col('dates') >= pl.lit(my_date_str).str.strptime(pl.Date, fmt=my_date_fmt))
```

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ dates               ┆ vals │
│ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
└─────────────────────┴──────┘
```

Just be sure to match the format to your date string.  For example,

```py
my_date_str="01/02/21"
my_date_fmt="%D"
```

I can't speak to the performance of this approach, but it provides an easy way to incorporate string variables into your code.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `python datetime` objects. They will be converted to polars `literal` expressions.

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

pl.DataFrame({
    "dates": [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 3)],
    "vals": range(3)
}).filter(pl.col("dates") > datetime(2021, 1, 2))
```

Or in explicit syntax: `pl.col("dates") > pl.lit(datetime(2021, 1, 2))`

Answer (score -1):

Hacky workaround for slightly neater code: Just use pandas!

`pd.to_datetime` takes a single string, and from testing with my own data as well as your example polars is very happy to work with the pandas datetime object it returns.

If importing from pandas just isn't possible for you then this is useless, but if you want unfussy string to date conversion ... [why not use pandas for what it's good at? :P](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OawrlVoQqSs)

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import to_datetime # or just import pandas as pd

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "dates": [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 3)],
    "vals": range(3)
})

my_date_str = "2021-01-02"
my_date = to_datetime(my_date_str) # or use pd.to_datetime
print(df.filter(pl.col('dates') >= my_date))
```

which produces:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬──────┐
│ dates               ┆ vals │
│ ---                 ┆ ---  │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64  │
╞═════════════════════╪══════╡
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 1    │
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 2    │
└─────────────────────┴──────┘
```